# mysql cursor using USE mydb;

Tags: mysql, cursor

I appreciate your answer.  I changed the procedure with your changes, but I've done something wrong.  Would you please tell me what is wrong with the code?
So I'll need to include the code at the end of the main question.
Attempt #2 is at the bottom.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this procedure?  The system tells me there is an error at:

```
DECLARE myemail_cursor CURSOR FOR 
USE v_db; SELECT DISTINCT u.mail FROM users u INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON u.uid=ur.uid INNER JOIN role r ON ur.rid=r.rid WHERE r.name = 'court administrator' AND from_unixtime(u.access) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

If I run USE mydb; SELECT...in a query it works fine.  Can I not use 'USE variable; select...' in a procedure?

```
   BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished, v_finished1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE v_email varchar(4000) DEFAULT "";
 DECLARE v_db varchar(400) DEFAULT "";

 DECLARE mydb_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'database' FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and table_name='users';

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = TRUE; 
open mydb_cursor;
get_mydb: LOOP
FETCH FROM mydb_cursor INTO v_db;
 IF v_finished THEN 
CLOSE mydb_cursor;
 LEAVE get_mydb;
 END IF;


 DECLARE myemail_cursor CURSOR FOR 
USE v_db; SELECT DISTINCT u.mail FROM users u INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON u.uid=ur.uid INNER JOIN role r ON ur.rid=r.rid WHERE r.name = 'court administrator' AND from_unixtime(u.access) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;


 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished1 = TRUE;

OPEN myemail_cursor;

get_myemail: LOOP
 FETCH FROM myemail_cursor INTO v_email';
 IF v_finished1  THEN 
   CLOSE myemail_cursor;
   SET v_finished1 = FALSE;
   LEAVE get_myemail;
 END IF;

 -- build email list
 SET email_list = CONCAT(v_email," ",email_list);

 END LOOP get_myemail;

CLOSE myemail_cursor;

 END LOOP get_email;

 CLOSE email_cursor;

 END LOOP get_mydb;


  END
```

Attempt #2.
I am getting this error: table 'v_db.users' doesn't exist
The first cursor only selects DBs where the table users exists, so I can't figure out why I"m getting the error.

```
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished, v_finished1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE v_email varchar(4000) DEFAULT "";
 DECLARE v_db varchar(400) DEFAULT "";

 DECLARE mydb_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'database' FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and table_name='users';

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = TRUE; 
open mydb_cursor;

get_mydb: LOOP
FETCH FROM mydb_cursor INTO v_db;
 IF v_finished THEN CLOSE mydb_cursor;
 LEAVE get_mydb;
 END IF;

BLOCK2: BEGIN
 DECLARE myemail_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT DISTINCT u.mail FROM v_db.users u INNER JOIN v_db.users_roles ur ON u.uid=ur.uid INNER JOIN v_db.role r ON ur.rid=r.rid WHERE r.name = 'court administrator' AND from_unixtime(u.access) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished1 = TRUE;


OPEN myemail_cursor;

get_myemail: LOOP
 FETCH FROM myemail_cursor INTO v_email;
 IF v_finished1 THEN 
CLOSE myemail_cursor;
   LEAVE get_myemail;
 END IF;

 SET email_list = CONCAT(v_email," ",email_list);
END LOOP get_myemail;

END BLOCK2;
END LOOP get_mydb;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

> [23.2.1 Stored Routine Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html)
>
> ...
>
> - When the routine is invoked, an implicit USE db_name is performed (and undone when the routine terminates). USE statements within stored routines are not permitted.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
...
DECLARE mydb_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT
    DISTINCT u.mail
  FROM
    v_db.users u
      INNER JOIN v_db.users_roles ur ON u.uid=ur.uid
      INNER JOIN v_db.role r ON ur.rid=r.rid
  WHERE
    r.name = 'court administrator' AND
    from_unixtime(u.access) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
...
```

Remember:

> [13.6.3 DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html)
>
> ...
>
> [DECLARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html) is permitted only inside a [BEGIN ... END](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html) compound statement and must be at its start, before any other
>   statements.
>
> ...

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I changed the procedure with your changes, but I've done something wrong.  Would you please tell me what is wrong with the code?
So I'll need to include the code in other answer.

Comment: @Milton: `v_db` is dynamic, so you will need a dynamic query ([13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)), however, declaring a dynamic cursor is not so simple, see [MariaDB/MySQL: Cursors for Dynamic SQL](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/mariadbmysql-cursors-for-dynamic-sql/).